# MySQL Profiling Does Not Work With Nested Function

Tags: mysql, performance, profiling

I am trying to profile some queries in MySQL, version:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
```

Starting off with the standard approach,

```
SET profiling = 1;
```

...and an example query:

```
SELECT  mer.name
FROM    merchants mer
JOIN (
        SELECT  mem.id, mem.merchant_id
        FROM    members mem
        WHERE   is_test_account(mem.email) = false # THIS CAUSES PROBLEMS!
     ) subquery
ON mer.id = subquery.merchant_id
GROUP BY mer.id;
```

The problem arises when I use **any custom function** inside the nested query, like illustrated above with `is_test_account`. Executing the query as displayed prevents it from appearing in the list of profiles, `SHOW PROFILES;` 
Removing the function from the inner query's `WHERE` condition fixes the problem!

For reference, the function `is_test_account` looks something like this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION is_test_account(p_email_addr VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNS BOOLEAN
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN (p_email_addr like '%demo.com'
        OR  p_email_addr like '%example.com'
           );
END//
```

Why would using a that function in the nested query prevent MySQL profiling to work?

Any insights to solving the problem would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `like '%..'` doesn't use index. [see MySQL Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: My question has nothing to do with indexes. The goal of profiling is to see where the query spends most of its time.